# ng-change witing select with ng-options not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I have this code

```
<select  ng-model="trabajadores.orderSelected"  ng-options="excel for excel in trabajadores.csv.result[1]" ng-change="console.log('changed')">
                        </select>
```

It suppose to console.log("changed") on selection changes, but it does not :(. Can you please help me with this issue?. (ng-options is working properly and ng-model is been evaluated)

Comment: `console.log` isn't an Angular expression - if you use an actual `$scope` function with a `console.log` in it - does it work?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/300zdjza/1/

Comment: checking with a function ... thanks for the fiddle

Comment: Thanks it worked ! :D please post it as an answer I will accept it due to the actual problem seems to be that apparently I cannot call console.log directly on ng-change, I need to call a function and console log inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If during development you want to use the output in the `console` of the view many times, it is not convenient to write under each time this function.

It is best to proceed as follows. Use the built-in angular directive `$log`.

Live example on [jsfidlle](http://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/300zdjza/4/).

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {}).run(function($rootScope,$log){
  $rootScope.$log = $log;
});

app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  $scope.trabajadores = {
    csv: {
      result: [0, ['e1', 'e2']]
    }
  };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="my-app">
  <div ng-controller="AppController">
    <select ng-model="trabajadores.orderSelected" ng-options="excel for excel in trabajadores.csv.result[1]" ng-change="$log.log('changed '+ trabajadores.orderSelected)">
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Of course, you can not leave this production code. But for `debug` mode it can be fully used.

With this you can use the `$log` in any controller without any additional work.

Comment: Really apretiated your comment. Actually the problem was that apparently I cannot call console.log directly on ng-change, I need to call a function and console log inside it. Thanks

Comment: You can call `console.log` inside `ng-change`. Please, check jsfiddle.

Comment: thanks I have checked this is actually the more accepted answer. thanks you all for your time